# Java different timezone offset in same timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm using "Asia/Bangkok" zone id.
That offset is from GMT UTC+07:00.

but when I did followings, then it is not +7:00 when set "01/01/1900 7:00:00.000"

```java
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("01/01/1900 7:00:00.000");

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(date.getTimezoneOffset());

Date date2 = dateFormat.parse("01/01/1900 6:00:00.000");
System.out.println(date2);
System.out.println(date2.getTimezoneOffset());
```

The result is

> Mon Jan 01 07:00:00 ICT 1900
> -402
> Mon Jan 01 06:00:00 ICT 1900
> -420

I wondered if the offset had changed around 7:00 a.m. on January 1, 1900, so I looked it up on Wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Thailand

It was UTC+6:42, but from 1880 to 1920.

I have 3 questions.

1. Why it happen different time offset between "01/01/1900 7:00:00.000" and "01/01/1900 6:00:00.000"
2. Where can I see time zone history in Java.
3. How can I ignore different time offset in same Timezone.

-- additional question --

I understand that I should use LocalDateTime.

What is the best way to ignore offset and convert Date to LocalDateTime?

For example, in the following case, the value of convertedDate2 was converted based on an offset of -402.

```java
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime originalLdate = LocalDateTime.parse("01/01/1900 7:00:00.000", dateFormatter);
LocalDateTime originalLdate2 = LocalDateTime.parse("01/01/1900 6:00:00.000", dateFormatter);

System.out.println(originalLdate);
System.out.println(originalLdate2);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("01/01/1900 7:00:00.000");
Date date2 = dateFormat.parse("01/01/1900 6:00:00.000");
LocalDateTime convertedDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime convertedDate2 = date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

System.out.println(convertedDate);
System.out.println(convertedDate2);

LocalDateTime convertedDate3 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFormat.format(date), dateFormatter);
LocalDateTime convertedDate4 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFormat.format(date2), dateFormatter);
System.out.println(convertedDate3);
System.out.println(convertedDate4);
```

The result is

> 1900-01-01T07:00
> 1900-01-01T06:00
> 1900-01-01T07:00
> 1900-01-01T05:42:04
> 1900-01-01T07:00
> 1900-01-01T06:00

If I convert it once to String and then to LocalDateTime, as in convertedDate3 and convertedDate4,
then I could convert as my expectation, but I wonder this is the most efficient way or not?

Answer (score 3):

Java runtime timezone information for each version is available here
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/tzdata-versions.html

Inside the linked file (for a specific version) you can find links to the actual data used

```
https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzcode2021a.tar.gz
https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdata2021a.tar.gz
https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdb-2021a.tar.lz
```

Inside the `tzdata*.tar.gz` you can find a file called `asia` which contains the data for Bangkok as well.

It contains these entries

```
# Thailand
# Zone  NAME            STDOFF  RULES FORMAT [UNTIL]
Zone    Asia/Bangkok    6:42:04 -     LMT    1880
                        6:42:04 -     BMT    1920 Apr # Bangkok Mean Time 
                        7:00    -     +07
Link Asia/Bangkok Asia/Phnom_Penh   # Cambodia
Link Asia/Bangkok Asia/Vientiane    # Laos
```

So the -402 timezone should be used for all dates before 1/4/1920, but it seems the implementation is using the -402 offset only from 1/1/1900 0:00:00.000 UTC (from 1/1/1900 6:42:04.000 in your timezone) and until 1/4/1920 in your timezone and -420 otherwise. I am not sure, if that is intended or a bug.

> How can I ignore different time offset in same Timezone.

If you are actually using timezones in your application, then you should not ignore them.
However, if you are making an application that is intended to be used just in your local timezone, then you can use a DateTime class without timezone information, such as `java.time.LocalDateTime`.
Also worth noting: even if these timezones would be correct, the historical dates might still be inaccurate, due to modern time rules being applied for all time (see below). So in the end it depends on what your use case is.

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system. The ISO-8601 calendar system is the modern civil calendar system used today in most of the world. It is equivalent to the proleptic Gregorian calendar system, in which today's rules for leap years are applied for all time. For most applications written today, the ISO-8601 rules are entirely suitable. **However, any application that makes use of historical dates, and requires them to be accurate will find the ISO-8601 approach unsuitable.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understand that I should use LocalDateTime. 
However, I have additional question how should I convert Date to LocalDateTime.
I've updated question, please take a look.
Thank you for in advance.

Answer (score 2):

java.util.Date and java.text.SimpleDateFormat are very old classes.  Although they mostly work, they are difficult to use properly, especially where timezones are concerned.

[Date.getTimezoneOffset is deprecated.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#getTimezoneOffset())  Do not use deprecated methods.

The proper way to work with timezone rules is using the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html), [java.time.zone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/package-summary.html), and [java.time.format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/package-summary.html) packages:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();

DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss.SSS");

LocalDateTime date =
    LocalDateTime.parse("01/01/1900 7:00:00.000", dateFormatter);

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(zone.getRules().getOffset(date));

LocalDateTime date2 =
    LocalDateTime.parse("01/01/1900 6:00:00.000", dateFormatter);

System.out.println(date2);
System.out.println(zone.getRules().getOffset(date2));
```

The entire history of a timezone is in the [ZoneRules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getRules()):

```
System.out.println();
zone.getRules().getTransitions().forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println();
zone.getRules().getTransitionRules().forEach(System.out::println);
```

You also asked:

> What is the best way to ignore offset and convert Date to LocalDateTime?

You can’t.  It is not possible to convert a Date to a LocalDateTime without assuming a timezone.

A Date is a wrapper for the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  You cannot generate a LocalDateTime from that without knowing which timezone to apply to that millisecond count.  For example, noon Eastern Time in the US is a different number of milliseconds since 1970 than noon Greenwich time.

You may not realize it, but when you use SimpleDateFormat, you **are** specifying a timezone.  Every SimpleDateFormat [has a timezone property](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)).  Since your code never set that timezone explicitly, your date format used the system’s default timezone.

That is one reason to avoid DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat:  the implicit use of the default timezone leads to errors and confusing behavior (though it is predictable behavior).  When you use the java.time package and its subpackages, there is no ambiguity, and far less chance of confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understand that I should use LocalDateTime. 
However, I have additional question how should I convert Date to LocalDateTime.
I've updated question, please take a look.
Thank you for in advance.

Comment: @tatata I’ve updated my answer to address your other question.